# Error connecting to server with python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

When I'm trying to connect a website using request module i'm getting an error Could Please help me in that?

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
print(response.status_code)
```

---

**Output:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:_PYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line
>   157, in _new_conn
>           (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
>         File "C:_PYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 84, in create_connection
>           raise err
>         File "C:_PYTHON\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py",
>   line 74, in create_connection
>           sock.connect(sa)
>       TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
>   or established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond
>
> ```
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> ```

Comment: Your code is working fine on my side, with 200 status code

Comment: It works for me. You might wanna check your internet connection and the library installation version.

Comment: Are you working inside any protected environment like a firewall or limited outward connectivity of internet?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issues seems to be server or network related.

Comment: Actually i'm Using Company providing lap , In this lap i'm unable to access with that code,Should i do any changes in browser settings?

Comment: @BollamReddy browser settings won't help, if it is a company provided computer, you might have vpn running which may interfere with the responses

Comment: Test one thing at a time. Start by trying to get a page that's running on your local machine like `python -m http.server`; if that works, try getting a page from your intranet; if that works, try getting an `http://`-based page from outside. Your problem could be with a large number of network-related issues, all of which may have solutions, but nobody here can provide a complete description of all of them (nor should they) - you may want to consider asking this question on a site like Server Fault instead https://serverfault.com/. There appears to be no issue with your Python.

Comment: if you are using inside office network, you might want to set proxy.